# how to add 3 months to '01-01-2014' in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How to add 3 Months to a given date and date format is 'dd-mm-yyyy' in mysql

```
   select DATE_ADD('01-01-2014', INTERVAL 3 Month)
```

while executing above query i am getting null

please help me to get a expected output...

Comment: `DATE_ADD` expects `yyyy/mm/dd` so you'll have to parse your string into that format first before using `DATE_ADD`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2014', '%d-%m-%Y'), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```